# helpe me to fix my code cant convert it from java to c#

Tags: c#

i have thies code by java to decrypt this sting
575-371-46b-576-362-276-528-634-731-330-53c-729-436

```
public static String decrypt(String str) {
    str = str.replace("-", "");
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 3) {
        result = result + ((char) (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i + 1, i + 3), 16) ^ Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)))));
    }
    return result;
}
```

i tray to convert to c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String str= "575-371-46b-576-362-276-528-634-731-330-53c-729-436";
str = str.Replace("-", "");
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; (i < str.Length); i += 3)
{
result = (result + ((char)((int.Parse(str.Substring((i + 1), (i + 3)), 16) | int.Parse(String.valueOf(str[i]))))));

}
textBox1.Text = result; }
```

but i didnt sucess to decrypt the string
i get alotof erorr but im still beginer in c# and i cant fix it

```
Error   1-'string' does not contain a definition for 'valueOf'  
Error   2-Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.IFormatProvider'
Error   3- The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid ar`enter code here`guments
```

Comment: You should consider the differences in the APIs between Java and C#. Search the appropriate API docs for C# [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/).

Comment: How is `int.Parse` meant to cope with the `b` and `c` in the input string? Can you explain how the computation is meant to work?

Comment: i tray to make that and get thies
   String str = "575-371-46b-576-362-276-528-634-731-330-53c-729-436";
             str = str.Replace("-", "");
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 3)
            {
                result = result + ((char)(Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(i + 1, (i + 3) - (i + 1)), 16) ^ int.Parse(str[i].ToString())));
            }

            textBox1.Text = result;

but disnt decrupt string

Comment: You need to about method `int.Parse` on MSDN and understand how to use it. This will help you understand why you are getting this error. `String.valueOf` gives the string representation of character. Try reading about converting character to string in C# and use that knowledge to solve the first error.

Comment: @Enigmativity thies function to convert the first string to txt you cane see java code

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i fixed it but disnt compleet ducript string it get to me prosat-2639.2

Comment: if I am not wrong `^` is a XOR operator in Java and `|` is OR operator in C#. So basically you are using different operator in C#. Read [Here](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/bitwise-operators#xor) about XOR operator in C#.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  ^ it mein Bitwise Exclusive OR in c#

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i expected  get user agent i get the java code from anthor app but i didnt know the user agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the C# that you're looking for:

```
result += (char)(int.Parse(str.Substring(i + 1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) ^ int.Parse(str[i].ToString()));
```

However, that's a bit horrid.

I would prefer this in C#:

```
var characters =
    str
        .Split('-')
        .Select(x =>
            int.Parse(x.Substring(1, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) ^ (x[0] - '0'))
        .Aggregate("", (a, c) => a + (char)c);
```

Or even:

```
string characters =
    String
        .Join(
            "",
            str
                .Split('-')
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    head = x.Substring(0, 1),
                    tail = x.Substring(1, 2),
                })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    head = int.Parse(x.head),
                    tail = int.Parse(x.tail, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                })
                .Select(x => x.head ^ x.tail)
                .Select(x => (char)x));
```

Comment: thanks but i get tihe erorr
Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 41 18 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Have you got `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file?

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an approved answer. However, seeing the glaring inefficiencies in the original Java code (such as adding up strings), I wanted to come up with my own slightly improved version in C#. Here goes:

```
private static int ParseXInt(string x, int i, int n) =>
    int.Parse(x.Substring(i, n),
              System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

public static string Decrypt(string s) =>
    new string(s.Split('-')
                .Select(x => (char)(ParseXInt(x, 0, 1) ^
                                    ParseXInt(x, 1, 2)))
                .ToArray());
```

Short, readable, reasonably efficient (in spite of using LINQ), and (in my opinion) elegant.